# String validation in C: Trying to ask for a new string when the old one has an invalid character

Tags: c, string, validation, input

I have a glitch in this code and am not sure how to fix it.

I would like to read an inputed string of random characters one character at a time.

Once an invalid character is read, I would like the program to stop reading the string and prompt the user to input a new string.

The program will also only read and store up to 5 characters regardless of string length unless the end of string is met before this 5 character limit.

code:

```
    int check; //1 = invalid char in string, 2 = otherwise
    char c;
    char seq[5]; 

    do{     printf("Enter a string of only "+" and "-" \n");

            for(i=0; c!=EOF || i<5 ; i++){
                    scanf("%c",&seq[i]);
                    if((seq[i] != '\x2b') || (oseq[i] != '\x2d')){
                            printf("invalid sequence, try again\n");
                            check=1;
                            break;
                    }
                    check=2;
            }

    }while(check==1);
```

Please help, I know it's a simple solution but it's just not coming to me and I've searched/tried everything.

I should add that this code keep reading and will print out every time it reaches an invalid char without letting the user input a new one until it reaches the end of the string.

Comment: You should split your `for` expression making read of `c` separate from the count of `i`. Perhaps a `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`. Additionally, if you use `getchar`, `c` should be an `int`. You then want a simple `queue` of chars with a max of 5 chars to store your 5-char history. There are many examples.

Comment: You should probably read in an entire line of input, validate it, and then decide to either use it or prompt the user to enter another line.  Otherwise, how would you know where the “invalid old” input ends and where the “better new” input begins.

Comment: I thought about doing this but couldn't figure out how I would check each individual character of the string to see if it is valid.

I can think of how to do it in java (string tokenizer) but what would be the equivalent operation in c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what your for current for loop is going to do:

```
        for(i=0; c!=EOF || i<5 ; i++){
```

For i starting with 0, run while c is not EOF or i is less than 5.

So if c is not EOF, i is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... 1000, because our code ignores i as long as "c != EOF".

Accessing seq[1000] is not what you want.

Moreso, as far as `c` is concerned, your initial iteration of the for loop checks for `c != EOF` but you never initialized c to a value. That is undefined behavior and c could be anything, so your loop may run or may never run of c happens to start out with the same value as EOF is defined as.

I recommend you just simplify to:

```
        for(i=0; i<5 ; i++){
```

Then keep your validity check inside the loop, if c is EOF or some other invalid value, use break to exit the for loop and keep your for(...) conditions simple. This change will fix both of the issues with your for loop.

Besides that, you stated the intention was to store up to 5 characters. In C, if you intend to treat the character array as a string, you must allow room for the trailing null terminating character, so always use N + 1 for your array size. You should use `seq[6]` if you intend to print it later, and make sure to set the last character of the string (after you read the last one) to 0 (or '\0').

Per your infinite loop problem you are being caught out by the age old beginner's luck of using scanf() which is a poor input function. I've been coding in C for 20 years and to be honest, I forgot how to use scanf effectively 19 years ago because it just is ill suited for most input needs (I love its brother printf, but thats a different story). scanf() will scan exactly what you ask for, but if it doesn't handle an input, it will leave it unscanned. If you consider when you input a character and hit return, you are actually entering 2 characters (counting the \n on UNIX or 3 on Windows/DOS counting \r\n). In your case, you are buffering up additional characters each iteration.

You can clear the input buffer with something like this after your scanf() call.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

But I avoid scanf() and use fgets() or getchar() directly. scanf() is to be avoided. All C programmers start by learning scanf() in school, then they eventually learn it is to be avoided for anything but formatted files.

Comment: Hmm I see what you're saying but my major issue is the edit. Once scanf reads in an invalid character and I try to check it using the if statement the code doesn't stop reading the string and immediatly prompt the user to enter a new string. It will print out "invalid string, try again""Please ender a string..." multiple times corresponding to the amount of invalid characters read. That is my major issue with this whole code.

Comment: See my edits, scanf() is your problem. Clear the input buffer, or otherwise handle the newline. If this is for school, ask the professor to allow you to use better functions like fgets(). scanf() or any other function that requires a specific input format is ill-suited to handle arbitrary user input on line buffered consoles.

Comment: Thank you for all the assistance! I completely rewrote the code and it does what I want now. This is but this is not the part of the problem or requirements so I will not be graded on it. In fact I don't even need to put in this code. It's just extra work to make it run smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not initializing the variable called 'c'...

perhaps declare it with

> char c = null;
> or
> char c = 0;

and use it in your loop

> scanf("%c",&c);
>
> seq[i] = c;

otherwise your check for c != EOF will be spurious / ambiguous / undefined

Also, the first time it enters the loop and checks for

```
for(i=0; c!=EOF || i<5 ; i++)
```

...you have not set the value for c - so anything could happen unexpectedly, and you are using OR instead of AND.  It should be:

> for(i=0; c!=EOF && i<5 ; i++)